# expiring a session in php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, security, web, websecurity

I have a question about expiring sessions in PHP.

so I have this site I'm implementing using PHP and javascript.
as one of the features I have aded live search using JSON AJAX and PHP.
and to secure the ajax call I'm passing a token (randomly-generated string) in the JS AJAX call URL and then storing it in a session as shown below:

generating the token and storing it in a session:

```
<?php
   $token = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())),0,20);
   $_SESSION["ajaxToken"] = $token;
?>
```

adding it to the ajax call URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/AuctionSystem/Ajax/searchAjax.php?q=" + str + "&token=<?php echo $token; ?>" , true);
```

the searchAjax.php:

```
<?php
require_once ('DataSet.php');
session_start();
$token="";

if(isset($_SESSION["ajaxToken"])) {
    $token = $_SESSION["ajaxToken"];
}
if (!isset($_GET["token"]) || $_GET["token"] != $token){
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->error = 'Token error';

    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $DataSet = new DataSet();
    $DataSet = $DataSet->search($_GET["q"]);
    echo json_encode($fDataSet);
}
```

my question is: how can I expire this "token" after a certain amount of time and enforce a page reload to generate a new one where should it be set

Comment: Sounds like you're after a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) (single-use token). The pattern you're implementing is called [_"CSRF prevention"_](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). Check out the linked article for examples and strategies

Comment: I have a similar work experience in the past which requires something like your case (require to expire a session after 10 minutes). My simple trick is to create another session variable say $_SESSION["ajaxTimeout"] which stores the current datetime, and then when after say 10 minutes you can do the part on "expiration" and page reload.